# A better way to get live streams from YouTube?

Tags: youtube-api

As far as I know, the only way to get the live stream video ID for a youtube channel would be to query the `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search` endpoint with the channel ID. This would return a list of live streams for that channel. On my website, I do this automatically every 5 minutes so that it can automatically check and announce when I go live.

The problem with this is that every search transaction has a query cost of 100. So scanning every 5 minutes for a single channel costs 28,800 queries a day. My website only has a quota limit of 30,000 a day. Which means I couldn't add a second channel to the scrape; because that would double the query costs.

Is there a better way to get the stream video ID for a channel besides the `search` endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ideas linked by @Marco, I came up with a better solution.

Scrape the channel's homepage and fetch it's html contents. I put them in the variable `$html`. Then I take those contents and run it through the following:

```
if (preg_match('#window\["ytInitialData"\]\s?=\s?(.+?);#i', $html, $matches))
{
    // this gets the YT's JSON for the channel

    $json = json_decode($matches[1], true);
    $json = $json['contents']['twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer']['tabs'][0]['tabRenderer']['content'];
    $json = $json['sectionListRenderer']['contents'][0]['itemSectionRenderer']['contents'][0];
    if (empty($json['channelFeaturedContentRenderer'])) { return; }
    
    // if there is no 'channelFeaturedContentRenderer' section, there are no live streams
    
    foreach ($json['channelFeaturedContentRenderer']['items'] AS $item)
    {
        if (empty($item['videoRenderer']['badges'])) { continue; }
        
        // if the video has no badges, its not a live stream.
    
        $stream = $item['videoRenderer'];
        
        // all the stream's details are available here
    }
}
```

Very easy. It also supports fetching all the streams on a channel; in case a channel has multiple streams at once.